# Can't change display driver on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, 20.04, nouveau

I recently installed 20.04 and I'm confused as I found this bug while changing my display drivers. While installing, I got my Nvidia drivers automatically installed, but they were buggy and had some fps drops (less than 19.10, but still uncomfortable) so I decided to choose Nouveau X.org ones. Apparently it worked, I rebooted my laptop and then I see this, please check the screenshot:

[image: Additional Drivers Bug]

It says "Using manually installed drivers" and at the end I don't know which one I'm using. Is this a bug? What can I do to clean select X.org Nouveau drivers and not Nvidia ones?
Thanks in advance.

Edit: Added output of command as asked.

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
    DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Dell UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP106M [GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Dell GP106M [GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

Also another clarification, I did ubuntu-drivers autoinstall and now everything seems ok, now I'm able to choose again and Nvidia Drivers are in use, but the output of the command is confusing me as it shows 4 kernel modules.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: Done, thanks for your reply, mind taking a look at it please?

Comment: Why post it as a screenshot? You can copy text from a terminal.

Comment: My bad, edited and it's text now

Comment: Si is everything resolved now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your terminal output, Nvidia proprietary driver is installed and in use.

You can remove this driver by running in a terminal:

```
sudo apt purge 'nvidia.*'
```

But if you installed Nvidia drivers without using apt, e.g. by running a `.run` file, this won't work.

Comment: If I do that the default Noveau drivers are installed? I wouldn't like to end up with no graphics at all

Comment: Nouveau ia always installed unless you deliberately remove it. The command removes only proprietary drivers.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else runs into this problem you don't need to use a terminal.

Programs like Synaptic and Muon both have the ability to show all the packages you have installed.  Simply type nvidia in the search and select the category of installed.  Then select all the packages, right click and select purge.  Now reopen the Additional Drivers gui and select the driver you would like to install.

This is muon, but synaptic looks pretty much the same.  The only difference between the two mostly is one is Qt and the other is GTK.  If you are on Gnome get Synaptic and if you are on Plasma get Muon.
[image: This is muon]