# Can't Change GPU Driver (Additional Drivers)

Tags: nvidia, gpu

When I open Software & Updates, I am told that I am using a "*manually* installed driver" (which is apparently *not* proprietary):
[image: Screenshot of "Additional Drivers" dialog box]

I'm not too sure *why* Ubuntu is telling me this, as I *explicitly* chose to use the latest version of Nvidia's proprietary driver when I "clean" installed Ubuntu on Launch Day... I installed this driver *via* the "Additional Drivers" tab of "Software & Updates".

Somebody asked a similar question over [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1235698/cant-change-display-driver-on-ubuntu-20-04), but when I followed the suggestion over there, I am told:

```
E: Unable to locate package nvidia.*
```

Here's the output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics (rev 02)
    DeviceName: VGA
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. UHD Graphics
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
--
02:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP108BM [GeForce MX250] (rev a1)
    DeviceName: Second VGA
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GP108BM [GeForce MX250]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

And the output of `inxi -SbCGxx` can be found over [here](https://pastebin.com/3aMPkneF).

How can I select Nvidia's proprietary driver in the "Additional Drivers" dialog box, to ensure that I am using the current (stable) version of their proprietary driver?

My laptop is the ASUS ZenBook Duo UX481FL, with an Nvidia GeForce MX250 GPU under Ubuntu 20.04 LTS ("Focal Fossa").

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Got it fixed... The way I did it was like this:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

Restart my laptop.

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Restart my laptop.

Re-install the *proprietary* driver via the "Additional Drivers" tab of "Software & Updates".

Restart my laptop.

I Went back into the "Additional Drivers" tab of "Software & Updates" - now it says I am using the latest proprietary driver ("450", at the time of writing).

Comment: Sorry for asking on a tangent, but would you overall recommend the Zenbook Duo with Ubuntu in terms of how the auxiliary screen is working?

Comment: Absolutely. The secondary (lower) display works perfectly with "touch" input "out of the box" - though the (optional) stylus doesn't work with it... There's a *probably* a way to get the stylus working, but I realized after I bought it that I don't actually have a need for the stylus, so I haven't looked into it. When I'm not at my desktop, I usually have my e-mail on the secondary (lower) display, and whatever I am working on shown on the primary (upper) display. You can use 'HydraPaper' to set a different wallpaper on each display.

Comment: If you have any other questions about the ZenBook Duo and Linux-based operating systems, feel free to shoot me a message and I'll try to answer them... I've been single-booting Ubuntu on the ZenBook Duo since it launched, so I've tried most things. You can get in contact with me using the webform on Opera.id.au.

Comment: I think the email logo at opera.id.au sends me to login to my non-existent web mail rather than send you an email, but I'm wondering whether Ubuntu works on the ZenBook Duo out of the box after installation, without rough edges concerning the typical fail areas such as monitor brightness, lack of fan control leaving the fans constantly over-active and other driver failures.

Comment: I meant to click the 'Contact me' link at the bottom of the page; the 'E-Mail' link is for my e-mail access from a browser. To answer your questions, the ZenBook Duo mostly works "out of the box" with Ubuntu. You cannot adjust the brightness of the secondary display - though there is a custom kernel floating around which resolves this (I never installed it, because it's not bothered me); you CAN adjust the brightness on the primary display perfectly. There is no option to control the fan speed, but it seems to work pretty well "out of the box" (i.e. doesn't work harder than necessary).