# Problem with lib-nih after upgrade to xubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, nvidia, package-management, xubuntu, gcc

I have the same issue as [this person](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1423358/lib-nih-unmet-dependencies-22-04). Just upgraded my Xubuntu, and got those messages during the upgrade - and, now when I try to install the updates for those packages, it doesn't work. I found an error log:

```
DKMS make.log for nvidia-470.141.03 for kernel 5.15.0-46-generic (x86_64)
Fri Aug 19 12:06:32 PM MDT 2022
make[2]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-46-generic'
arch/x86/Makefile:142: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
make[2]: /usr/bin/gcc: No such file or directory
test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (        \
echo >&2;                           \
echo >&2 "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";       \
echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
echo >&2 "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";  \
echo >&2 ;                          \
/bin/false)
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: gcc (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1) 11.2.0
  You are using:           
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/470.141.03/build \
single-build= \
need-builtin=1 need-modorder=1

The C compiler '/usr/bin/gcc' does not appear to be able to
create object files.  Please make sure you have 
your Linux distribution's libc development package
installed and that '/usr/bin/gcc' is a valid C compiler
name.

*** Failed CC sanity check. Bailing out! ***

make[2]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/470.141.03/build/Kbuild:194: cc_sanity_check] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: *** [Makefile:1881: /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/470.141.03/build] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-46-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:80: modules] Error 2
```

This is for one of the processes that tried to run after it installs, or fails to install, the NIh libraries.

Using `apt-cache policy` as recommended in one of the comments on the previous question, I see all sources for Jammy, none for Bionic.

Additionally, I am now having an issue with my display - it won't let me change the resolution, staying stubbornly stuck at 1024x768. I assume this is because it can't update the nvidia drivers or something, but it's hard to be sure.

Comment: Looking at the output for apt list --upgradable, I get:
libnih-dbus1/jammy 1.0.3-12build1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.0.3-6ubuntu2]
libnih1/jammy 1.0.3-12build1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.0.3-6ubuntu2]
which are both AMD packages... But, my processor is an 'Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6500'. Maybe that's the source of the problem?

Comment: I ran 'sudo apt autoremove', removed 616 obsolete packages, used synaptic to uninstall the two NIH packages cause problems and their dependents, and then switched my nvidia driver to the x.org open source driver - and while my computer no longer complains about being unable to update the NIH libraries, I still can't change my screen resolution. Additionally, the drivers page now claims that it's using a manually installed driver, which is not the case, and it won't let me change it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I managed to solve it!

First, I ran 'sudo apt autoremove', removed 616 obsolete packages, used synaptic to uninstall the two NIH packages causing problems and their dependents, and then switched my nvidia driver to the x.org open source driver After this, my computer no longer complained about being unable to update the NIH libraries, but I still couldn't change my screen resolution. Additionally, the drivers page claimed that it's using a manually installed driver, and wouldn't let me change it. To solve this problem, I followed the instructions as per [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1276886/cant-change-gpu-driver-additional-drivers), and changed to the most recent nvidia driver. After that, everything worked properly.